# memory js game pictures won't close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found one game on js, and I want to add it to myself by redoing it a bit

https://jsfiddle.net/a7Lx1c98/

So, I want to replace emoji with pictures here, I do this

```
const emojis = ['https://i.imgur.com/GLS9S5f.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/IN9C2qz.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/Ke2ubzv.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/PbvJDyR.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/L3ysai2.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/1NxzhTV.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/aksV9O3.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/gYsZdE4.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/LXo6iW3.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/wYrEwNR.jpg']
const picks = pickRandom(emojis, (dimensions * dimensions) / 2) 
const items = shuffle([...picks, ...picks])
const cards = `
  <div class="board" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(${dimensions}, auto)">
    ${items.map(item => `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-front"></div>
        <div class="card-back"><img src="${item}"></div>
      </div>
    `).join('')}
  </div>
`
```

As a result, the pictures appear, but the game itself does not work, when you select two pictures and they are different, they do not close, but you can choose everything in a row

What could be wrong?

```js
const selectors = {
    boardContainer: document.querySelector('.board-container'),
    board: document.querySelector('.board'),
    moves: document.querySelector('.moves'),
    timer: document.querySelector('.timer'),
    start: document.querySelector('button'),
    win: document.querySelector('.win')
}

const state = {
    gameStarted: false,
    flippedCards: 0,
    totalFlips: 0,
    totalTime: 0,
    loop: null
}

const shuffle = array => {
    const clonedArray = [...array]

    for (let index = clonedArray.length - 1; index > 0; index--) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1))
        const original = clonedArray[index]

        clonedArray[index] = clonedArray[randomIndex]
        clonedArray[randomIndex] = original
    }

    return clonedArray
}

const pickRandom = (array, items) => {
    const clonedArray = [...array]
    const randomPicks = []

    for (let index = 0; index < items; index++) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * clonedArray.length)
        
        randomPicks.push(clonedArray[randomIndex])
        clonedArray.splice(randomIndex, 1)
    }

    return randomPicks
}

const generateGame = () => {
    const dimensions = selectors.board.getAttribute('data-dimension')

    if (dimensions % 2 !== 0) {
        throw new Error("The dimension of the board must be an even number.")
    }

    const emojis = ['https://i.imgur.com/GLS9S5f.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/IN9C2qz.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/Ke2ubzv.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/PbvJDyR.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/L3ysai2.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/1NxzhTV.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/aksV9O3.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/gYsZdE4.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/LXo6iW3.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/wYrEwNR.jpg']
const picks = pickRandom(emojis, (dimensions * dimensions) / 2) 
const items = shuffle([...picks, ...picks])
const cards = `
  <div class="board" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(${dimensions}, auto)">
    ${items.map(item => `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-front"></div>
        <div class="card-back"><img src="${item}"></div>
      </div>
    `).join('')}
  </div>
`
    
    const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(cards, 'text/html')

    selectors.board.replaceWith(parser.querySelector('.board'))
}

const startGame = () => {
    state.gameStarted = true
    selectors.start.classList.add('disabled')

    state.loop = setInterval(() => {
        state.totalTime++

        selectors.moves.innerText = `${state.totalFlips} moves`
        selectors.timer.innerText = `time: ${state.totalTime} sec`
    }, 1000)
}

const flipBackCards = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.card:not(.matched)').forEach(card => {
        card.classList.remove('flipped')
    })

    state.flippedCards = 0
}

const flipCard = card => {
    state.flippedCards++
    state.totalFlips++

    if (!state.gameStarted) {
        startGame()
    }

    if (state.flippedCards <= 2) {
        card.classList.add('flipped')
    }

    if (state.flippedCards === 2) {
        const flippedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.flipped:not(.matched)')

        if (flippedCards[0].innerText === flippedCards[1].innerText) {
            flippedCards[0].classList.add('matched')
            flippedCards[1].classList.add('matched')
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            flipBackCards()
        }, 1000)
    }

    // If there are no more cards that we can flip, we won the game
    if (!document.querySelectorAll('.card:not(.flipped)').length) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            selectors.boardContainer.classList.add('flipped')
            selectors.win.innerHTML = `
                <span class="win-text">
                    You won!<br />
                    with <span class="highlight">${state.totalFlips}</span> moves<br />
                    under <span class="highlight">${state.totalTime}</span> seconds
                </span>
            `

            clearInterval(state.loop)
        }, 1000)
    }
}

const attachEventListeners = () => {
    document.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const eventTarget = event.target
        const eventParent = eventTarget.parentElement

        if (eventTarget.className.includes('card') && !eventParent.className.includes('flipped')) {
            flipCard(eventParent)
        } else if (eventTarget.nodeName === 'BUTTON' && !eventTarget.className.includes('disabled')) {
            startGame()
        }
    })
}

generateGame()
attachEventListeners()
```

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(325deg,  #6f00fc 0%,#fc7900 50%,#fcc700 100%);
    font-family: Fredoka;
}

.game {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
    background: #282A3A;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Fredoka;
    font-size: 18pt;
}

.disabled {
    color: #757575;
}

.stats {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.board-container {
    position: relative;
}

.board,
.win {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgb(33 33 33 / 25%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #6f00fc 0%,#fc7900 50%,#fcc700 100%);
    transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.board {
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.board-container.flipped .board {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.board-container.flipped .win {
    transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #282A3A;
    transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
    font-size: 28pt;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: #FDF8E6;
}

.card.flipped .card-front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.card.flipped .card-back {
    transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}

.win {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FDF8E6;
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.win-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 21pt;
    color: #282A3A;
}

.highlight {
    color: #6f00fc;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Memory Game in JavaScript</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css" />
        <script src="assets/game.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="game">
            <div class="controls">
                <button>Start</button>
                <div class="stats">
                    <div class="moves">0 moves</div>
                    <div class="timer">time: 0 sec</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="board-container">
                <div class="board" data-dimension="4"></div>
                <div class="win">You won!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you see the `Dev Ed` tutorial on youtube?

Comment: What has your debugging revealed?  When you step through the `flipCard` and `flipBackCards` functions, what specifically fails or doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @David I did not meet any errors, just all the pictures are considered correct for some reason

Comment: Maybe it's because flippedCards is read only as text

Comment: @davyjones: "No errors" doesn't mean "works correctly".  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the runtime behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *every pair* is a match:

```
if (flippedCards[0].innerText === flippedCards[1].innerText)
```

Your elements have no text, so `innerText` is always an empty string.  So any two cards, regardless of their images, match.

Probably the quickest solution is to compare the HTML instead:

```
if (flippedCards[0].innerHTML === flippedCards[1].innerHTML)
```

Assuming the rest of the HTML is always the same, the only different *should* be the `src` on the `<img>` element(s).

---

As an added exercise, you could also look into being more explicit in that comparison.  Perhaps give each element a `data-*` property and compare those instead of relying on the text or HTML.  Or perhaps specifically read the `src` property and compare those values instead of comparing the entire contents of the element(s).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is comparing the `innerText` of the two cards. There is no inner text, so you can compare the card back image URLs.

```js
const selected = [...flippedCards].map(card => card.querySelector('.card-back img').src);

if (allEqual(selected)) {
  flippedCards[0].classList.add('matched')
  flippedCards[1].classList.add('matched')
}
```

I also added an `allEqual` function to make sure all the items match:

```js
const allEqual = arr => arr.every(v => v === arr[0]);
```

### Working example

```js
const allEqual = arr => arr.every(v => v === arr[0]);

const selectors = {
  boardContainer: document.querySelector('.board-container'),
  board: document.querySelector('.board'),
  moves: document.querySelector('.moves'),
  timer: document.querySelector('.timer'),
  start: document.querySelector('button'),
  win: document.querySelector('.win')
};

const state = {
  gameStarted: false,
  flippedCards: 0,
  totalFlips: 0,
  totalTime: 0,
  loop: null
};

const shuffle = array => {
  const clonedArray = [...array];

  for (let index = clonedArray.length - 1; index > 0; index--) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1));
    const original = clonedArray[index];

    clonedArray[index] = clonedArray[randomIndex];
    clonedArray[randomIndex] = original;
  }

  return clonedArray;
}

const pickRandom = (array, items) => {
  const clonedArray = [...array];
  const randomPicks = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < items; index++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * clonedArray.length);

    randomPicks.push(clonedArray[randomIndex]);
    clonedArray.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  }

  return randomPicks;
}

const generateGame = () => {
  const dimensions = selectors.board.getAttribute('data-dimension');

  if (dimensions % 2 !== 0) {
    throw new Error("The dimension of the board must be an even number.");
  }

  const emojis = [
    'https://i.imgur.com/GLS9S5f.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/IN9C2qz.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/Ke2ubzv.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/PbvJDyR.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/L3ysai2.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/1NxzhTV.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/aksV9O3.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/gYsZdE4.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/LXo6iW3.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/wYrEwNR.jpg'
  ];
  const picks = pickRandom(emojis, (dimensions * dimensions) / 2);
  const items = shuffle([...picks, ...picks]);
  const cards = `
  <div class="board" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(${dimensions}, auto)">
    ${items.map(item => `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-front"></div>
        <div class="card-back"><img src="${item}"></div>
      </div>
    `).join('')}
  </div>
`;

  const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(cards, 'text/html');

  selectors.board.replaceWith(parser.querySelector('.board'));
}

const startGame = () => {
  state.gameStarted = true
  selectors.start.classList.add('disabled');

  state.loop = setInterval(() => {
    state.totalTime++;
    selectors.moves.innerText = `${state.totalFlips} moves`;
    selectors.timer.innerText = `time: ${state.totalTime} sec`;
  }, 1000);
}

const flipBackCards = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card:not(.matched)').forEach(card => {
    card.classList.remove('flipped');
  })

  state.flippedCards = 0;
}

const flipCard = card => {
  state.flippedCards++;
  state.totalFlips++;

  if (!state.gameStarted) {
    startGame();
  }

  if (state.flippedCards <= 2) {
    card.classList.add('flipped');
  }

  if (state.flippedCards === 2) {
    const flippedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.flipped:not(.matched)')
    const selected = [...flippedCards].map(card => card.querySelector('.card-back img').src);

    if (allEqual(selected)) {
      flippedCards[0].classList.add('matched')
      flippedCards[1].classList.add('matched')
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      flipBackCards();
    }, 1000);
  }

  // If there are no more cards that we can flip, we won the game
  if (!document.querySelectorAll('.card:not(.flipped)').length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      selectors.boardContainer.classList.add('flipped');
      selectors.win.innerHTML = `
                <span class="win-text">
                    You won!<br />
                    with <span class="highlight">${state.totalFlips}</span> moves<br />
                    under <span class="highlight">${state.totalTime}</span> seconds
                </span>
            `;

      clearInterval(state.loop);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

const attachEventListeners = () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const eventTarget = event.target;
    const eventParent = eventTarget.parentElement;

    if (eventTarget.className.includes('card') && !eventParent.className.includes('flipped')) {
      flipCard(eventParent);
    } else if (eventTarget.nodeName === 'BUTTON' && !eventTarget.className.includes('disabled')) {
      startGame();
    }
  })
}

generateGame();
attachEventListeners();
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(325deg, #6f00fc 0%, #fc7900 50%, #fcc700 100%);
  font-family: Fredoka;
}

.game {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background: #282A3A;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Fredoka;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.disabled {
  color: #757575;
}

.stats {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.board-container {
  position: relative;
}

.board,
.win {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgb(33 33 33 / 25%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #6f00fc 0%, #fc7900 50%, #fcc700 100%);
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.board {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.board-container.flipped .board {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.board-container.flipped .win {
  transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #282A3A;
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
  font-size: 28pt;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #FDF8E6;
}

.card.flipped .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.card.flipped .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}

.win {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FDF8E6;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.win-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 21pt;
  color: #282A3A;
}

.highlight {
  color: #6f00fc;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="controls">
    <button>Start</button>
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="moves">0 moves</div>
      <div class="timer">time: 0 sec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="board-container">
    <div class="board" data-dimension="4"></div>
    <div class="win">You won!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```